# Javadoc: How to show parameters like buttons?

Tags: android-studio, javadoc

In Android Studio, the parameters of some classes are showing like this:

[image]

It looks really clean and easy to read. How can I achieve this effect in my javadocs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the way the Javadoc looks by modifying the stylesheet that is at the root of your javadoc, usually <javadoc_root>/stylesheet.css

For instance, with Java 6, when I add:

```
dd dl dd code { border: 1px outset #000000 }
```

this results in:

[image]

With Java 7, if I add:

```
ul.blockList li.blockList ul li dd code { border: thin inset #FFFFFF; padding: 2px }
```

this results in:

[image]

As you can see, this changes a few more elements than just the parameter names. This is due to the fact that there isn't by default a single CSS class which allows to distinguish them from all other elements. For that you'd need to write a custom [doclet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking maybe it was a straightforward thing (like a special HTML tag or something). But thanks anyway.